# How to create Non Editable column in telerik framework ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I am using the telerik MVC framework Grid component and i want to make the id column of the grid to be visible but not editable.
Also i want data of the field to be send to the server when user creates a new row.

for this i am using the following code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyApplication.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Title("Code");
          columns.Bound(c => c.companyName).Title("Company Name");
          columns.Bound(c => c.address).Title("Address");
          columns.Bound(c => c.addressNumber).Title("Street").Width(60);
          columns.Bound(c => c.zipCode).Title("ZIP Code").Width(60);
          columns.Bound(c => c.city).Title("City").Width(80);
          columns.Bound(c => c.province).Title("Province").Width(45);
      })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Sortable(sortable =>
      {
          sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn);
      })
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 710px; top: -25px" })
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
          toolbar.Create();
          toolbar.Save();
          toolbar.Excel();
          toolbar.Pdf();
      })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Batch(true)
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
          .Model(model =>{
                // Declare a model field and make it readonly
                model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);
                        })
          .Read(read => read.Action("CustomerListViewModels_Read", "Customer"))
          .Create(create => create.Action("CustomerViewModels_Create", "Customer"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("CustomerViewModels_Update", "Customer"))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("CustomerViewModels_Destroy", "CustomerList"))
      )
     .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

You set this when you configure the datasource. Here you can tell the grid which field is the id and or make any field that is bound read only by calling .Editable(false).

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyApplication.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Title("Code");
      columns.Bound(c => c.companyName).Title("Company Name");
      columns.Bound(c => c.address).Title("Address");
      columns.Bound(c => c.addressNumber).Title("Street").Width(60);
      columns.Bound(c => c.zipCode).Title("ZIP Code").Width(60);
      columns.Bound(c => c.city).Title("City").Width(80);
      columns.Bound(c => c.province).Title("Province").Width(45);
  })
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
  .Sortable(sortable =>
  {
      sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn);
  })
  .Scrollable()
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 710px; top: -25px" })
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
      toolbar.Create();
      toolbar.Save();
      toolbar.Excel();
      toolbar.Pdf();
  })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
       .Model(mdl =>
       {
         mdl.Id("ID");//Tell the grid which field is the id
         mdl.Field(fld => fld.ID).Editable(false);//Make the id field read only
       })
      .Batch(true)
      .Read(read => read.Action("CustomerListViewModels_Read", "Customer"))
      .Create(create => create.Action("CustomerViewModels_Create", "Customer", new { id = "#:data.ID#" }))
      .Update(update => update.Action("CustomerViewModels_Update", "Customer"))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("CustomerViewModels_Destroy", "CustomerList"))
  )
 .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))
    )
```

Comment: I have already implemented this but this also restrict the gird from sending the data to the server. just see the code few line below

Comment: @AjayChaudhary I added something to the code to pass the id...I forgot you needed to pass the ID on create...However the model configuration should not be preventing this form happening.